# Checking number of actually allocated pages using anonymous mmap()

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, mmap

I'm allocating some memory using `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag. Because of the problem's features, often I need to write some data to one page ( for example, located in the middle ) of large memory chunk, and leave the other part untouched. So, I wouldn't this rather big part of unused memory to allocate physically.

In my view, such `mmap()` call just give me a pointer to some 0-filled virtual pages, but due to to copy-on-write and demand paging mechanisms, no one page ( besides first maybe ) isn't actually allocated in RAM until first write attempt to it's memory.

The problem is: one moment I've got `MAP_FAILED` from `mmap()` ( there were a lot of successful calls with fewer allocation queries before ), when tried to allocate a memory chunk larger than my physical RAM size. So, it seems there are much more pages actually allocated, even if there wasn't write access to them.

I need your help guys with two questions, first: 
Is my views to anonymous memory allocation correct, and (if not) , what are the inaccuracies?

And the second: 
How could I measure number of actually allocated pages after anonymous `mmap()` is done? I've tried use `mincore()`, and it's results show me that almost all pages are "resident" in memory ( i.e., physically allocated? ). So, it seems `mincore()` results are wrong, or I'm totally stuck :(

**Upd.** 
It seems memory overcommiting mentioned by @Art indeed could influence this. But when I'm trying to disable it ( setting `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to `1` mode or using `mmap()` with `MAP_NORESERVE` flag, my machine is heavily freezing, and hard reset is the only thing that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's complicated." (caveat: I have much more experience of VM systems from not Linux, but I've picked up a few details from Linux over the years)

Generally your assumption is true. Many operating systems don't actually do much on `mmap` other than record "there is an allocation of X pages of object Y at V". Access to those pages causes a page fault which leads to an actual allocation. Some (or maybe all?) versions of Linux map a pre-zeroed read-only page to such allocations (not sure if it has changed or if it's still done) and the rest is handled like copy-on-write (for me it feels like a bad idea because it should generate more TLB flushes for a dubious optimization of reading zeroed memory which should happen rarely, but I guess Linux people have benchmarked it and found it good).

There are a few caveats. Just because you don't use the RAM doesn't mean that you'll be allowed to overcommit so much memory. Certain Linux distributions started default to a setting that disallows overcommit or disallows more than X% overcommit. Centos/RedHat was one of those (this was probably a decade ago, I don't know the state today). This means that even when you're just using 5% of your actual physical memory, if you have created anonymous mappings of 100+X% of your RAM, mmap will fail. There is a sysctl for it, look it up. It's something like `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` or `overcommit_ratio` or both, or probably even more under there.

Then you have to be aware of resource limits. Check with `ulimit` if you're allowed to create mappings that big (ulimit -v), the problem could be as simple as that. Also (I'm not sure how Linux does it here, but you can create simple test programs to try it), resource limits for data size (ulimit -d) can be accounted as potential pages you can use rather than actual pages you currently use (in other words no overcommit in resource limits).

Then let's get back to faulting in only the pages you use. There has been research into detecting access patterns and predicting future faults (so that mmap:ed files could do read-ahead), but I don't know the state of it in Linux. It feels like it would be dumb to apply this to anonymous mappings, but you never know, maybe someone is trying to be clever. To make sure, use `madvise(..., MADV_RANDOM)` on the mmap:ed block you get.

Finally `mincore`. My experience from it on Linux is that it's garbage, last time I tried it it didn't work for anonymous mappings (or was it private?). In your case it could be as simple as it reporting that the read-only copy-on-write zeroed page for anonymous mappings is considered to be "in core".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please advise a more reliable way to test what pages are faulted, and what are not? I've found some syscalls and terminal commands ( `top`, `ps`, `pmap` ...), but it seems they couldn't help me to check my assumptions about (not-) allocated pages

Comment: I've not been able to figure out a way to do it reliably. The best I've found when I needed it was to use perf tools to count page faults for me. But that's only useful for debugging.